# How to make sub queries with success with multiple parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `PA_Ledger` and `PA_Trans`. I just wrote a stored procedure that filters with date, inner join, group by `PA_Ledger.Name` and sorts by that name.

I have a stored procedure that finds records with join,group by and date filter as like :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      Shalin Gajjar
-- Create date: 27/10/221
-- Description: get all report data
-- =============================================
--exec [dbo].[PA_Report_IndexPagingData] 100,1,'Oct  28 2021 12:00AM','Oct  30 2021 12:00AM','Order By Name Asc',''
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PA_Report_IndexPagingData]
    --10,1,'Order By Name Asc','',3
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @PageSize int,
    @PageIndex int,
    @startdt1 nvarchar(50),  
    @startdt2 nvarchar(50),
    @Sort nvarchar(50),
    @Search nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @TotalRecords nvarchar(max)

    SET @TotalRecords=' ( select count(*) from PA_Ledger pl join PA_Trans pt on (pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeridcr or pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeriddr ) 
                         where isnull(Isdeleted,0) = 0 and pl.Name like ''%'+@Search+'%'' 
                          and (pt.TransOn >= '''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt1,110))+''' or convert(date,'''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt1,110))+''') = convert(date,''01/01/1900'') )
                         and (pt.TransOn <='''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt2,110))+''' or convert(date,'''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt2,110))+''') = convert(date,''01/01/1900'') )
                         group by pl.Name)'
    

    
    set @qry = ' select  *, '+@TotalRecords+' As TotalRecords,                  
                        (select row_number() over(order by pl.name) as RowNo,pl.Name,sum(pt.Amount) as Amount
                         from PA_Ledger pl
                         join PA_Trans pt on (pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeridcr or pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeriddr)
                         and pl.Name like ''%'+@Search+'%'' and
                         isnull(Isdeleted,0) = 0 
                         and (pt.TransOn >= '''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt1,110))+''' or convert(date,'''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt1,110))+''') = convert(date,''01/01/1900'') )
                         and (pt.TransOn <='''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt2,110))+''' or convert(date,'''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt2,110))+''') = convert(date,''01/01/1900'') )
                         group by Name 
                        ) i where RowNo between  '+Convert(nvarchar(10),( (@pageIndex-1) * @pageSize  ) + 1 )+ ' and '  + Convert(varchar(10),( (@pageIndex-1) * @pageSize  ) + @pageSize) + ' '+ @Sort

    
    print(@qry)             
    exec(@qry+@TotalRecords)
    
END
```

When I execute then generate error like :

```
( select count(*) from PA_Ledger pl join PA_Trans pt on (pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeridcr or pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeriddr ) 
                         where isnull(Isdeleted,0) = 0 and pl.Name like '%%' 
                          and (pt.TransOn >= 'Oct 28 2021 12:00AM' or convert(date,'Oct 28 2021 12:00AM') = convert(date,'01/01/1900') )
                         and (pt.TransOn <='Oct 30 2021 12:00AM' or convert(date,'Oct 30 2021 12:00AM') = convert(date,'01/01/1900') )
                         group by pl.Name)
 select  *,  ( select count(*) from PA_Ledger pl join PA_Trans pt on (pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeridcr or pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeriddr ) 
                         where isnull(Isdeleted,0) = 0 and pl.Name like '%%' 
                          and (pt.TransOn >= 'Oct 28 2021 12:00AM' or convert(date,'Oct 28 2021 12:00AM') = convert(date,'01/01/1900') )
                         and (pt.TransOn <='Oct 30 2021 12:00AM' or convert(date,'Oct 30 2021 12:00AM') = convert(date,'01/01/1900') )
                         group by pl.Name) As TotalRecords,
                        
                        (select row_number() over(order by pl.name) as RowNo,pl.Name,sum(pt.Amount) as Amount
                         from PA_Ledger pl
                         join PA_Trans pt on (pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeridcr or pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeriddr)
                         and pl.Name like '%%' and
                         isnull(Isdeleted,0) = 0 
                         and (pt.TransOn >= 'Oct 28 2021 12:00AM' or convert(date,'Oct 28 2021 12:00AM') = convert(date,'01/01/1900') )
                         and (pt.TransOn <='Oct 30 2021 12:00AM' or convert(date,'Oct 30 2021 12:00AM') = convert(date,'01/01/1900') )
                         group by Name 
                        ) i where RowNo between  1 and 100 Order By Name Asc
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
> Invalid column name 'RowNo'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
> Invalid column name 'RowNo'.
>
> Msg 263, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
> Must specify table to select from.
>
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
> Invalid column name 'Name'.

What is the better solution for this stored procedure? Please help me to get out of this situation.

Comment: Subqueries are used after FROM. You are using them between SELECT and FROM - you can't do this. When there is a parenthesis with something at that place, sql server expeects a single value, not a (derived) table. Move your subqueries.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis please help me with with your code.

Comment: This code is dangerous, you should parameterize properly via `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you haven't given us create/insert queries, so we have to go blind. Try changing the first line of your `set @qry`:

```
set @qry = ' select  *, '+@TotalRecords+' As TotalRecords,
```

to this:

```
set @qry = ' select  *, '+@TotalRecords+' As TotalRecords, i.* from
```

This will cause your parenthesis `(...) i` to be a derived table instead of a single value, and we SELECT all its elements `, i.*`

Also, change @totalrecords to this version with alternate aliases:

```
set @TotalRecords=' ( select count(*) from PA_Ledger pl2 join PA_Trans pt2 on (pl2.LedgerId = pt2.Ledgeridcr or pl2.LedgerId = pt2.Ledgeriddr ) 
                         where isnull(Isdeleted,0) = 0 and pl2.Name like ''%'+@Search+'%'' 
                          and (pt2.TransOn >= '''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt1,110))+''' or convert(date,'''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt1,110))+''') = convert(date,''01/01/1900'') )
                         and (pt2.TransOn <='''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt2,110))+''' or convert(date,'''+convert(nvarchar,CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt2,110))+''') = convert(date,''01/01/1900'') )
                         group by pl2.Name)'
```

Comment: changed but error occurs like  select  *,  ( select count(*) from PA_Ledger pl join PA_Trans pt on (pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeridcr or pl.LedgerId = pt.Ledgeriddr ) .......
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Ambiguous column name 'Name'.

Completion time: 2021-11-01T14:41:09.5418717+05:30

Comment: Ah ok, that's because you've used the same alias (eg pl) on both `@TotalRecords` and `@qry`. Change the aliases in one of them, eg pl->pl2, pt->pt2 etc

Comment: please update your code.. this will help me a lot

Comment: Added the `@TotalRecords` change